# unable to launch a program with different options from a .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I need help with a task:

I have a program that can make different reports.
I know how to launch this program in a .bat file as it is.
But I don't know how to launch it with an option of making one or another report.

Can someone help me figure out how to solve this issue?

Comment: The type of task you are referring to would always be program specific.  There is no common way to do this with a batch file.  The program would need to be able to take command line arguments for this to execute correctly. If the program is a graphical user interface, then you have no options at all.  Batch files cannot interact with graphical user interfaces.

Comment: Ok, got it.  
Thank you.

Comment: See if there is there is a `help` or `?` option that shows you the parameters for the line command…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what program is the program?

do you happen to know any of the variables to launch the program with? usually when you open them in a batch you put the other variables after it such as -t -cd -s43 or something like that. also the program doesnt do it itself or does it only run different reports when you configure it with the arguments?

is this the type of program that uses a Config file that you can toggle arguments?

I know a little about this and id have made this a comment if i could.

if it runs from a batch file or something like that, you could make a batch file that would launch it with the appropriate options by using

```
SET /P _INPUTNAME= Please input:
IF "%_INPUTNAME%"=="1" GOTO :Report1D
IF "%_INPUTNAME%"=="2" GOTO :Report2D
```

and so on and so forth by using this:

```
:Report1D
```

as a header that the GOTO command uses so that you have the arguments and the batch file to be loaded under that header. this allows for menu like navigation within a batch file. id advise using PAUSE under it and GOTO and make a tag/headder to go back to the main menu ya created when its finished with the report.

ive done this with another file, you can use it as a template

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Selection Menu, Self explanitory ::
:: Each GOTO a specific tag in code ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:Selection
CLS
COLOR 7C
ECHO.
ECHO        Deletion menu.
ECHO    Choose a selection Option:
ECHO.
ECHO   REGULAR USER COMMANDS:
ECHO.
ECHO   V:\ Drive BAK / ERR Files         : 1
ECHO   Y:\ Drive wip/master BAK Files    : 2
ECHO   Y:\ Drive wip/master ERR Files    : 3
ECHO   Y:\ + V:\ .LOG File Removal       : 4
ECHO   Y:\ TMP/BAD/CSV/HTML File Removal : 5
ECHO.
ECHO   To Exit This Program            : Quit
ECHO.
ECHO      ADMINISTRATORS ONLY COMMANDS:
ECHO.
ECHO   Y:\ Drive ALL BAK/ERR FILES     : Admin
ECHO.

SET /P _INPUTNAME= Please input:
IF "%_INPUTNAME%"=="1" GOTO :DelV_BNE
IF "%_INPUTNAME%"=="2" GOTO :DelY_bak
IF "%_INPUTNAME%"=="3" GOTO :DelY_err
IF "%_INPUTNAME%"=="4" GOTO :Del_log
IF "%_INPUTNAME%"=="5" GOTO :Del_misc
IF "%_INPUTNAME%"=="Q" GOTO :QUIT
IF "%_INPUTNAME%"=="q" GOTO :QUIT
IF "%_INPUTNAME%"=="quit" GOTO :QUIT
IF "%_INPUTNAME%"=="Quit" GOTO :QUIT
IF "%_INPUTNAME%"=="QUIT" GOTO :QUIT
IF "%_INPUTNAME%"=="Admin" GOTO :ADMIN
IF "%_INPUTNAME%"=="ADMIN" GOTO :ADMIN
IF "%_INPUTNAME%"=="admin" GOTO :ADMIN
IF "%_INPUTNAME%"=="a" GOTO :ADMIN
IF "%_INPUTNAME%"=="A" GOTO :ADMIN

CLS

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::   ERROR CODE for MENU    ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:END_OF_LINE
CLS
COLOR 0C
ECHO.
ECHO.      
ECHO        IMPROPER  REQUEST 
ECHO          ACCESS DENIED 
ECHO.
PAUSE
GOTO :Selection

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Deletes BAK / ERR Files on the V Drive ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:DelV_BNE
CLS
Echo.
Echo    PROCESS STARTED
ECHO    Deleting .BAK Files
ECHO    This might take a minute...
Echo.
   V:
cd \PPY005\Facilities Management\
del /S /Q /F *.bak
CLS
echo.
ECHO    BAK FILES DELETED
ECHO    Deleting .ERR Files
ECHO    This might take a minute...
Echo.
V:
cd \PPY005\Facilities Management\
del /S /Q /F *.err
CLS
COLOR E3
Echo.
ECHO    FINISHED
ECHO.
Pause
CLS
GOTO :Selection
PAUSE
GOTO :Selection

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Self Explanitory, quits the program ::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:QUIT
EXIT
```

this is from a utility i created, use it as a template to do what you need to do but you need to be WAYYYY more specific if you want us to help you. 
i mean unless i know what we are dealing with, im not sure how to do this. does it have a user interface? is it command line?

Comment: well let me know the problem. we cant offer a solution unless we know what we are doing here. How are you launching it? how does it not work? show me the code and show me what you are doing and ill troubleshoot this with ya

Comment: I did not specify the problem because I thought that there is some kind of common template for such cases.  
The program name is Sinko.exe - it is a synchronisation module for another program. Thi module is created basically for making different reports & data import-export. At this time there is no config file for this app.   
But the point is, as I understand, that I will be able to make the laucnhing I need only with typing clearly defined options exactly for this module ? I.e. there is no some common options/commands for cases like mine ?

Comment: Each program is unique, some programs have specific things you can do to run them with a special argument to force the program to start up with specific paramiters. usually its specific to the program and without it i cant help

take this program for example: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6152425?hl=en they have specific flags and arguments you can run the program with. id advise looking up any documentation you have on the program as i cannot find anything online on it and this was the first result when i looked it up, and i doubt these are the command line arguments for this program.

Comment: @echo
start " " "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Sinko.exe 
exit


That is my .bat for this app.
So, as I said, I can laucnh It but I don't know how to specify the launching

Comment: do you happen to have any documentation?

@echo 
start " " "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Sinko.exe -t
Pause
 exit

see how i placed the -t argument after the exe? also i advise you to use PAUSE so that you can see any error that pops up if there is a mistake. do you have any ability to find arguments you can use with this program? arguments to alter a program are always specic to the program as these were made by the programmer.

does the file use a .cfg or config file of any type?

Comment: Daggerfella, thanks a lot.  
I'll try to solve It using your advises.  
I understand that this is an off-top without a config file for the program.

Comment: contact whom ever you got the file from as im not even sure, only result when looking for "Sinko.exe" that was even in english was this https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/d78a06013a80ba3f039164feb7841104c96cde1496e643c67f0dc90f17b6450d?environmentId=100 and it says its encryption software and potentially malware.

im guessing its a custom program, contact whomever made it. We do not know the command arguments for the program to run differently unless i can get specifics.. either you will have to run the program, alter the program or find the arguments that can be made after the .exe.

Comment: your welcome, hope you can figure it out. but atleast you know how to put these arguments down on paper. upvote my comment and select it as an answer if you feel like this has solved your question. and even if you have other questions later, feel free to drop a comment here.